# Transparent image(gif) has black background in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-ion

I have fragment which has ViewPager:

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="350dp"                   
                     />
```

Adapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter
...
@Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {        
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);            
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

            Ion.with(context)
            .load(path)
            .withBitmap()
            .intoImageView(imageView);     

            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;
        }
...
}
```

If image is transparent, it has black background.
Set white bg for fragment root view or activity root view did not help.

Answer (score 1):

I think transparent gifs are not supported on android as per this link
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62016
so it is better to use png

Comment: The same image which is loaded in RelativeLayout without ViewPager has  android:background="@color/WHITE" and it works.

Comment: But use png image because android recommends that and everybody use same